# What Math is used in Development Economics?

Tags: mathematical-economics, development-economics

I would like to ask what kind of math is used in Development Economics?

I have one more semester in my Master of Math programme before hopefully entering a PhD in Economics and am considering specializing in this; so I would like to know what I should take or review next semester.  Are the topics listed on the wiki-page for Mathematical Economics applicable?  Being differential equations, linear algebra, optimization, and analysis.  Or would statistics or data science be more applicable?

Thank you

Comment: Most research in development economics is empirical nowadays. Especially randomized control trials are very in, so I would look into that as well as into microeconometrics in general. I would definitely give statistics and econometrics (not necessarily time series or macroeconometrics) priority. However your math skills will come very much in handy in getting through the first year of a phd program, during which you won't have much time for research.

Comment: There isn't any. None.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does depend on whether you're looking to do applied econometric work, in which case statistics is definitely the way to go or something theoretical, in which case a good understanding in the maths you listed will go a long way. Of course it's always better if you understand both - since you're doing a master's in math, you should already be quite fluent with the math required, so I'd go with econometrics.

There's a growing amount of literature available, but if you have time to spare, I'd give the topics in Nafziger's "Economic Development" a glance: http://tabesh.edu.af/Books/economic/Economic%20Development.pdf

Comment: I see thank you, and thank you very much for the pdf link too it looks like a superb introduction to this! :D

Comment: No problem. Hopefully it'll help you get started with some ideas for research. :)